# Stratified sampling help in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 600 participants. I would like to get an approximate representative sample of this df based off age, sex, gender, site, and education of n=20. it doesnt need to match exactly, but R doesnt like that it doesnt match exactly. So far, i have tried this code but it isnt working. any tips?

```
sample_size <- 30 
sampled_data <- IGNITE %>% 
  group_by(screen_gender, age_nih_reg, screen_site,  educ,  screen_race) %>% 
  sample_n(size = sample_size, replace = FALSE) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

> ```
> Error in `sample_n()`:
> ! Can't compute indices.
> ℹ In group 1: `screen_gender = 1`, `age_nih_reg = 65`, `screen_site = 1`,
>   `educ = 13`, `screen_race = 1`.
> Caused by error:
> ! `size` must be less than or equal to 1 (size of data).
> ℹ set `replace = TRUE` to use sampling with replacement.
> Backtrace:
>   1. ... %>% ungroup()
>  15. base::local(...)
>  16. base::eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
>  17. base::eval(expr, p)
>  18. base::eval(expr, p)
>  19. base::eval(...)
>  20. base::eval(...)
>  21. dplyr:::check_size(sample_size, n(), replace = replace)
> ```

Comment: `sample_n` has been superseded by `slice_sample`, which I believe will do what you want. (_"If `n` is greater than the number of rows in the group (or `prop > 1`), the result will be silently truncated to the group size."_)

Comment: Why not simply take a random sample?

Comment: @Axeman: This won't help because typical group size is probably 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your groups are too small, the simple approach fails.

I once hacked something like this into {splitTools}, a package that does data splitting for ML tasks.

There are two steps:

1. Run kmeans to cluster the rows by the specified features. Features are scaled. Ordinal factors are integer encoded and normal factors/character vectors are dummy encoded. Don't make too many clusters. In the code below, I used 6, which is probably too large.
2. Do a stratified split using cluster ids to get the desired group size.

```r
library(splitTools)

set.seed(1)

# Factor with cluster id
s <- multi_strata(iris[2:5], strategy = "kmeans", k = 6)

# Split indices
ix <- partition(s, p = c(big = 0.96667, small = 0.03333), type = "stratified")
lapply(ix, length)
iris[ix$small, 2:5]

# #  Result
#     Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 10          3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
# 25          3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa
# 28          3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 52          3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 63          2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
# 98          2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
# 116         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica
# 148         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica
```